# Block K2 tag pages from being indexed by search engine

Tags: k2, tags, seo

I have K2 blog and some articles have tags. When people click on tag e.g. "summer" they get all articles related to "summer" but that creates duplicated content.

How can I set all K2 tag pages to have no index, no follow robots rules?

Comment: You want to block the tagged items list pages, that show all items of a specific tag?

Answer (score 2):

You may have to insert a meta tag manually for each page into a block of content that you do not want robots to index.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

OR

You can go into your robots.txt file and disallow by url/path

```
Disallow: /page/to/your/path
```

Comment: That's the only way?

Comment: Definitely not you could always try going to your robots.txt file and doing a disallow by url like such

Disallow: /your_url

Comment: I ment only "joomla" way :D

Comment: I'd definitely look into adding it a disallow rule in your robots.txt file because you could do it setting a block on all paths that begin with a certain string

Comment: updated answer, if you go this route please let me know if it was successful or not